# Python Snake Game Cell Positions with Lists

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame

I am trying to create a game of snake with a possibility of 100 cells (snake parts or length). In each iteration of the main while loop each cell position takes the position of the one in front of it. When I attempted doing this it returns:

```
cellPosX[100 - x] = cellPosX[100 - (x + 1)] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code, I didn't think all of it was necessary.

```
cellPosX = [100]
cellPosY = [100]
cellPosX[0] = 400
cellPosY[0] = 300

#Change Cell Positions
for x in range(0, 100):
    cellPosX[100 - x] = cellPosX[100 - (x + 1)]
    cellPosY[100 - x] = cellPosY[100 - (x + 1)]
```

I am only a beginner to programming in python and I haven't gotten used to it yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually initializing the lists?

Comment: Huh? Not completely sure, All I have done with the lists is whats here, how do you suggest I do it. Sorry if my mistake is silly.

Comment: BTW, if you start from zero, `range(100)` will do. And better define a constant `BOARDSIZE = 100`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just initializing lists with one item on them:
Better to initialize the whole 100 positions:

```
cellposX = [100]     # is a list with only one '100' inside
cellposX = [100]*100 # is a list with 100 '100' inside
```

Anyway, the way you are trying to implement this is not the properly one to do so in my opinion.
Check the code on [Snake Pygame Example](http://pygame.org/project-Snake+in+35+lines-818-.html) to learn.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the "*100" thing.